# In Android is it possible to transfer ownership of a touch event?

Tags: android

I am developing a modal movie player that changes mode based on gestures. At the moment the different modes are separated into individual ImageViews, since each mode's composition and interaction is distinct.

I am holding the views in a single ViewGroup. The ViewGroup will ensure that only one ImageView is visible at any time. The views will be togged via gestures.

One such gesture is a drag. Currently I am handling gestures within the ImageViews, and via callbacks triggering the ViewGroup to switch views.

I am having a problem with transfer of the move action from the current view to the switched view. The current view detects the move touch event, then triggers the switch. However, the new view does not see the remainder of the touch event.

My question is, is it possible to transfer ownership of a touch event from one view to another?

Comment: I don't think transferring in the middle of touch event is possible. However, you could manually stimulate the event in the next view. I once stimulate a scroll gesture when user press a button, so it should be.

Comment: Did you solve this?  I have a similar situation.  Thanks